# How to get Inserted Text in any textfield in custom keyboard ios

Tags: ios, custom-keyboard

[image]

I am creating **custom keyboard in ios** .and one problem I **can not figure out how to get full inputted string**.because that string I want to use in my code for mapping with *my dictionary database* and mapping word will be displayed in my collection view.

Comment: Show us your custom keyboard first.

Comment: Question is not clear enough.

Comment: @SyedSadrulUllahSahad i am creating roman English keyboard which will give me an urdu suggestion for exaple when i type one word (kia) in english in suggestion bar out somthing like ( کیا ) basically with-in application i know my textfield name and get a inputed text eg  NSString *str=self.txtField.text ;    but in outside for example in whatsapp or any other massenger how i get text .beacuse i didnot know the name of textfield .i am sorry for my english

Comment: So,you are dealing with custom keyboard and of course you have your keyboard button's click functions,for example UIButton action for touch up inside. What you have to do is get characters on button press from uibutton's text and make string by appending every character. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can use `[self.textDocumentProxy documentContextBeforeInput]` to get the whole current string visible.
This will return the string before cursor.

Answer (score 0):

From button action get text and make string what you want.

```
NSString *someString;// Global
- (IBAction)characterButtonAction:(UIButton *)sender {
        someString = [someString stringByAppendingString:sender.titleLabel.text];
}
```

Comment: Thankyou @Syed Sadrul Ullah Sahad.

Comment: Sir this string can also support backspace key in it forexaple when press backspace key or space key how i remove that word from my someString

Comment: try another answer

Comment: You are very helpfull person i am stuck with this situation around 3 week and i m beginer you help me a lot.

Comment: How to use in my code this line of code [self.textDocumentProxy documentContextBeforeInput] . to get inputed string i didnot get know to to use please guid me..

Comment: e-g .    NSArray *arrayOfSplitsString = [self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];      like use

Comment: NSString *someString = [self.textDocumentProxy documentContextBeforeInput]; like this when you need the string .

Comment: Thanks @Syed Sadrul Ullah Sahad